# How do I find the object type of a pointer handle

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a handle to a window with several children. I have enumerated the child windows and am left with a list of pointers. How can I find out the type of object for each pointer.

I am running a C# program and Pinvoking. The program that I am trying to find the objects of was written in C++.

My first thought was to try the following but that did not work.

```
button_1 = (Button)Marshal.PtrToStructure(c_pinpoint[5], typeof(Button));
```

Comment: You can't.  A pointer by itself is not enough to identify what it is.  You _must_ maintain that information somewhere or come up with a scheme to extract some metadata from the address or what's pointed to.

Comment: How come Spy++ can tell me that it is a button? How can I do the same thing?

Comment: @timi2shoes because it likely first turns it in to a base class like a `Control` and it can read the information it needs from there, re-casting to a Button as needed (I don't know if that will work in C# because Spy++ is not using C# so it would not be calling `Marshal.PtrToStructure`)

Comment: Spy++ operates on different objects. You compare apples and oranges. Spy++ operates on window handles. And they have class names.

Comment: @David I have window handle pointers, how is that different?

Comment: A window handle is not the same thing as a `Button`. The latter is a .net managed object. A very different beast from a window handle which is a Win32 GUI object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx) to find out the name of the window's class.

Note that you cannot realistically expect to obtain a C# object from a window handle. For a start the window handle may not be associated with a C# object. The program might not be a C# program. And the window handle may be in a different process.

Perhaps what you really need to be doing is using UI Automation to explore and automate this application.